# justify-content affecting the children of children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to constrain content in a `div` that has zero or more of height, width, max-height, or max-width set. If the content is smaller than the container in either dimension, it must be centered in that dimension; if it's larger, it must be scrollable in that dimension and start scrolled to the top/left.

This renders as I expected, with the image and text scrolling around, and the top-left corner of the image showing initially:

```html
<div style="background-color:red;max-width:10rem;max-height:10rem;overflow:auto">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/123/400/300.webp">
  </div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

This is the full image:

[image]

This doesn't render as I expected (note the addition of `display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center`):

```html
<div style="background-color:red;max-width:10rem;max-height:10rem;overflow:auto;display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/123/400/300.webp">
  </div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

If I remove `justify-content`, then initially the top-left of the image is displayed, as expected. However, the content is no longer centered vertically if it is smaller than the container.

My questions are:

- Why is `justify-content` affecting the scrollability and placement of the content? Shouldn't it only affect the immediate children of the div it's set on?
- How do I achieve the effect I need?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5m4hec27/

Comment: not sure why you are surprised since you are setting a column direction and changing the vertical alignment of the div (and at the same time the image inside it)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why do people post things like this in comments instead of answers? Now I can't respond directly to you. — Why would justify-content affect the vertical alignment of the image? It's not a direct child of the element with display:flex. That's part of my question: Why is that happening? And how do I avoid that?

Comment: image is inside a div that is affected by the alignment. If an element is affected by the alignment then its child will be affected too

Comment: @TemaniAfif Setting justify-content:unset on the image or its parent div has no effect. Is there a way to have justify-content only affect direct children? How would you achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="background-color:red;max-width:50rem;height:10rem;overflow:auto;display:flex;justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/123/400/300.webp">
  </div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Please check the code snippet and try to run it. Try to play with the value of height and width.

1. If container width is more than the child elements, Child elements will be horizontally centered automatically because of the justify-content property.
2. If container width is less than the child width, then it will show a horizontal scrollbar because of the overflow property.
3. If container Height is more than the child element, Child elements will be vertically centered automatically because of the align-items property.
4. If container height is less than the child width, It will show a vertical scrollbar because of the overflow property.

Note : 1. justify-content is not affecting the scroll ability
2. How to achieve the effect - Please see the Fiddle attached.

Comment: Your solution doesn't display the full image (like the top of the image). See "This is the full image" in the post. I'm aware of how to use justify-content and align-items. I omitted align-items to simplify the illustration of the problem.

Comment: Did you tried to increase the height of the main container?

Comment: No, because the container may or may not have an explicit height set.